# Curious link edit to cached archive.org link

Tags: discussion, edits

I came across an edit I don't understand:  https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5344074/5

Basically a link to http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/2 was replaced with http://web.archive.org/web/20140328224025/http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/2 .  This would make perfect sense if the original link didn't work, but it seems to be working fine...

Normally I'd just revert the edit, but it was done by a moderator.  Am I missing something?

Comment: For what it's worth, the old link doesn't seem to work for me. Edit: If I change it from https:// to http:// it does, though. Odd. Might be my network here.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the change I made there...  I first tried http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/ and it redirected me to https://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object , then I added the "/2" at the end and copy-pasted it here.  The original seemed to work for me, though.

Comment: Could it have been some automated bot edit?  Maybe the link happened to be down at the moment of testing...

Answer (score 19):

We received a flag that the link was no longer working. I tried the initial link, it failed so I replaced it with the archive version of it.

Comment: Wonder why that someone didn't just edit themselves. Probably even less work than raising a flag.

Comment: Yup, it's definitely not something a moderator needs to be involved in.

Comment: ;) okay, I thought maybe it was that, but I just thought it odd.  I reverted the change (no need to waste a moderator's time more).  Thanks for responding.